# enabling shortcut in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I disabled a shortcut ctrl+1 so nobody could insert a new row in my vba formular. The problem is I would like to have it restored after I close the workbook. I managed to restore the right click menu on column and row but I don't know how to re-establish the shortcut.

Code:

```html
Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.CommandBars("Row").Enabled = False
Application.CommandBars("Column").Enabled = False
Application.OnKey "^{+}", ""
End Sub


Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Application.CommandBars("Row").Enabled = True
Application.CommandBars("Column").Enabled = True

End Sub
```

Thanks for your replies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very similar to disabling it:

```
Application.OnKey "^{+}"
```